# Azure AD B2C custom policy - Getting Duplicate Code Error while logging in using authenticator app verification

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure B2C custom policy, I am facing the below error while signing into a web app with Microsoft authenticator app verification.

"Duplicate verification code entered, please try again.

[image]

I even tried setting up MFA with google authenticator in both Android and iOS devices but getting the same Duplicate verification code entered error.

Comment: You have to wait until new code is generated.